# SimpleMessageListenerContainer unable to call message handler correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm trying listen to a RabbitMq queue in my Spring Boot application. In my `RabbitConfig.java` file, I have the following beans:

```
// RabbitConfig.java
// ...Queue, exchange, binding beans, etc

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
    container.setPrefetchCount(100);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
    return container;
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate getTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper));
    return template;
}
```

I've created a listener container as I need to make some settings to it such as its prefetch count.

I've also created another class as the message listener which looks like this:

```
@Component
public class MyMessageListener {
    @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_NAME)
    public void messageHandler(MyMessageObj message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
        // process message...
}
```

However, when I run the application, it throws an error of `Error Handler converted exception to fatal`. The error appears to occur because the container was expecting  `messageHandler` to have a different method signature.

I'm thinking I might have done something incorrect in the container because when I remove it, the application is able to run and listen to the queue except that I can't configure the settings in the container.

What have I done wrong and what should I do to have the container use the `messageHandler` correctly?

Comment: >`@Bean`
>`SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)`
What is this container? It has no listener. The listener container for the `@RabbitListener` is created by the listener container factory configured using Boot properties. You need to show the full stack trace so that we can understand what the conversion exception is.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to implement a MessageListener class that implements org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener and implements the method "onMessage(Message message)"

Once you have a @Configuration class where you have defined the SimpleMessageListenerContainer, you need to have a corresponding Class that implements org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener and implements the method "onMessage(Message message)".

Let me know if this helps.

@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {

```
private static String queue = "ARRQueue";
@Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(){
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(new Queue(queue, true));
    simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener());
    return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
}
```

}

public class MessageListener implements org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        System.out.println("MessageListener.onMessage : " + new String(message.getBody()));
    }